# NVM not installing in W11

Tags: ubuntu, github, nvm

I have been trying to install NVM on my Ubuntu system, but the application does not install or download for some reason. I even went straight to the GitHub repository, but it's still not working. I have confirmed that it's not a connection problem; the status of GitHub shows that all servers and systems are working fine. So, I don't know what to do.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQBHW.png)

Comment: What commands have you tried?